# Azure Devops - Docker Compose Build Image Not Found

Tags: docker-compose, rabbitmq

I am having an issue getting an image to build in Azure Devops from a docker-compose file.

It appears that the first issue is that the image does not build.
[image]

This is, I believe, causing the push step to fail, as there is no created image, it is just running an existing image.

[image]

What can I do to "force" the process to build an image off of this to pass into our repo?  Here is our current docker compose file
    version: '3.4'

```
services:
  rabbit:
      image: rabbitmq:3.6.16-management
      labels:
        NAME: "rabbit"
      environment:
        - "RabbitMq/Host=localhost"
      ports:
        - "15672:15672"
        - "5672:5672"
      container_name: rabbit
      restart: on-failure:5
```

Here's the build and push steps (truncating the top which doesn't really matter)
Build:
[image]
Push:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent a fair amount of time fighting with this today (similar issue, anyway).  I do not believe the image being non-local is necessarily your problem.

Looks like you are using the "**Docker Compose**" Task in Azure DevOps for your Build.  I had the same problem - I could get it to build fine, but couldn't ever seem to "pipe" the result to the Push Task.  I suspect one could add another Task between them to resolve this, but there is an easier way.

Instead, trying using the "**Docker**" Task to do your build.  Without really changing anything else, I was able to make that work and the "Push" step next in line was happy as could be.
[image: Docker Task]

Comment: While we had other issues, this does indeed solve the problem outlined in this question, thanks.